# how to Move state dynamically using image click within Datagrid itemRenderer?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air, flash

I used play button image within datagrid item renderer, if I click image then move to another state (by using currentState ='play'). So I tried like:

```
<mx:DataGridColumn  textAlign="center"  headerText="" dataField="col2">
 <mx:itemRenderer>
  <mx:Component>
  <mx:HBox  textAlign="center"  paddingLeft="17">
         <mx:Image   source="@Embed(source='image/play_button.png')" click="currentState='Playsystem'"/>
    </mx:HBox>
  </mx:Component>
 </mx:itemRenderer>
```

But it shows error like undefined state 'Playsystem'. But Already I have state. What did I wrong? Why error shows like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because currentState is not a defined property of Component.

You need to change `click="currentState='Playsystem'"` to `click="this.parent.parent.parent['currentState'] = 'Playsystem'"`

as in:

```
<mx:DataGrid bottom="0" top="37" left="0" dataProvider="{dataAry}" width="340">
<mx:columns>
<mx:DataGridColumn  textAlign="center"  headerText="" dataField="col2">
 <mx:itemRenderer>
  <mx:Component>
  <mx:HBox  textAlign="center"  paddingLeft="17">
         <mx:Image   source="@Embed(source='125x125.gif')" click="this.parent.parent.parent['currentState'] = 'Playsystem'"/>
    </mx:HBox>
  </mx:Component>
 </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:DataGridColumn>
</mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

But I wouldn't do that way. It's kinda hacky. What I recommend is actual write a class for the component and have it listen and dispatch the click event to the container. [More info](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstart/handling_events/)

Comment: Thank you Ammar so much for your information i will change class for the component .